# Trouble with parsing CSV files in C#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I'm trying to import a CSV file to my C# site and save it in the database. While doing research I learned about CSV parsing, I've tried to implement this but I've ran into some trouble. Here is a portion of my code so far:

```
string fileext = Path.GetExtension(fupcsv.PostedFile.FileName);

if (fileext == ".csv")
{
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/CSVFiles/") + Path.GetFileName(fupcsv.PostedFile.FileName);

    fupcsv.SaveAs(csvPath);

    // Add Columns to Datatable to bind data  

    DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();

    dtCSV.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("ModuleId", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("CourseId", typeof(int))});

    // Read all the lines of the text file and close it.  

    string[] csvData = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath);

    // iterate over each row and Split it to New line.  

    foreach (string row in csvData)
    {

        // Check for is null or empty row record  

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {

            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(csvPath))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    //Process row
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (char cell in row)
                    {
                        dtCSV.NewRow()[i] = cell;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error "There is no row at position -1" at " dtCSV.Rows[dtCSV.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;"
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Would be better if you could post the entire exception and if possible link to the csv file on which you tried the code.

Comment: add the row to datatable, before assigning the value to it's row's.

Comment: The first part of the exception is "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code". Not sure how to put csv file up but its just two rows off numbers

Comment: You should use `ReadAllLines` instead of `ReadAllText`/`Split`.

Comment: When I change File.ReadAllText(csvPath); to File.ReadAllLines(csvPath); it throws up an error; "Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to index rows that you have not created. Instead of

```
dtCSV.Rows[dtCSV.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
```

use

```
dtCSV.NewRow()[i] = cell;
```

I also suggest you start indexing `i` from `0` and not from `1`.

**All right so it turns out there were a bunch of errors with your code, so I made some edits.**

```
string fileext = Path.GetExtension(fupcsv.PostedFile.FileName);

if (fileext == ".csv")
{
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/CSVFiles/") + Path.GetFileName(fupcsv.PostedFile.FileName);

    fupcsv.SaveAs(csvPath);
    DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();    
    dtCSV.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("ModuleId", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("CourseId", typeof(int))});

    var csvData = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath);
    bool headersSkipped = false;
    foreach (string line in csvData)
    {
        if (!headersSkipped)
        {
            headersSkipped = true;
            continue;
        }
        // Check for is null or empty row record  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            //Process row
            int i = 0;
            var row = dtCSV.NewRow();
            foreach (var cell in line.Split(','))
            {
                row[i] = Int32.Parse(cell);
                i++;
            }
            dtCSV.Rows.Add(row);
            dtCSV.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I ditched the TextFieldParser solution solely because I'm not familiar with it, but if you want to stick with it, it shouldn't be hard to reintegrate it.

Here are some of the things you got wrong:

- Not calling `NewRow()` to create a new row or adding it to the table with `AddRow(row)`
- Iterating through the characters in `row` instead of the `fields` you parsed
- Not parsing the value of `cell` - it's value type is `string` and you are trying to add to an `int` column

Some other things worth noting (just to improve your code's performance and readability :))

- Consider using `var` when declaring new variables, it takes a lot of the stress away from having to worry about exactly what type of variable you are creating
- As others in the comments said, use `ReadAllLines()` it parses your text file into lines neatly, making it easier to iterate through.
- Most of the times when working with arrays or lists, you need to index from 0, not from 1
- You have to use AcceptChanges() to commit all the changes you've made

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting this error:  "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot find column 2." Thanks

Comment: Yeah thats it working! Thanks for helping and taking the time to explain my errors to me, really appreciate it

Comment: Happy to help !